# If most of my Play code is blocking anyway, does it make sense to increase the number of threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have read a lot about how Play's non-blocking approach works. Ideally, incoming requests are supposed to be blazing fast, off-loading heavy-duty work to a worker thread, and returning to the pool for servicing more requests. That's one of the reasons that initially the pool of application threads is very close to the number of available cores on the machine's CPU. Numerous sources even warn against tinkering with the pool at all.

Let's face it though. In reality, not all part of the codebase can be made purely non-blocking. In fact, the bigger my application became, the more it started resembling a traditional Java-based server app. The alternative to making everything non-blocking and going around commodity JVM frameworks is just too costly.

I started questioning Play's original proposition. The question is should I really increase the default thread pool? Would this have any unexpected consequences (besides, of course, increasing the memory footprint)?

Comment: Have you read https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ThreadPools ?